# Cross-Process Locking in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I've written an API that will be used on the same box in (1) a windows service, (2) a web application, and (3) a windows forms application.  They all need to share a very small set of common data (a few ints, a date, and a string that I could put as properties of a single class).

What sort of locking mechanism can I use cross-process so that the three processes can share the resources safely and not run into conflicts?

No databases please, looking for a solution that doesn't require additional dependencies. Preferably the solution would use shared memory, or the file system in some way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For cross-process locking in C#/.Net, you can use a [named system Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Use an [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df414y9h.aspx) object to construct a named event that each process can lock or block on.  Works in .NET 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, it sounds like what you need it cross process communication. So one of the processes hosts the shared data and the other processes need to access that data.

If the above is correct, you could use simple in process locking like a Monitor to protect the shared data and expose a WCF endpoint to provide access to the data from another process. Using a Named Pipe transport for the WCf communication, will be very efficient for communication between processes on the same box.

There would be no need for cross process locking, unless you used a shared resource like a memory mapped file to share the data, but to be honest this would be cumbersome and require you to handle many things manually that WCF would take care of with the benefit that you could eventually scale of the single box to multiple boxes if you ever needed to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28VS.85%29.aspx) to provide shared queues between your applications, with one of the applications acting as the master; the Windows service would be the best choice if it's always running.

I use [System.Data.Sqlite](http://www.phxsoftware.com) for communicating between Windows services and applications. Even though you said no databases, you might find this a worthy compromise. It's an embedded database with no admin burden. You "ship" it by including a single DLL in your applications, and it saves your data in a single file.

Think of it as a persistent file that you access using SQL statements via ADO.Net; it even sports a LINQ interface. You get locking through standard transactions (with rollback) and it also offers encryption. You can modify and view its contents using the Visual Studio Service Explorer. It works on .Net 3.5 and .Net 4. And it's open-source with no restrictions. You can add columns and tables without breaking existing functionality. Since deployment is as simple as adding a DLL to your solution, it's much easier to deploy and support. And since the connection string points to a file, it makes it easy to hit it from remote machines. Perhaps not as elegant as shared queues or mutexes, but its greatly simplified things for me.

Comment: "Even though you said no databases, you might find this a worthy compromise." Doubtful, considering it's both a database and an additional dependency; both of which he explicitly dismissed as solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If all your application would reside on one machine, than you could use interprocess synchronization primitives like named mutexes and shared memory.

But I think much better approach would be to use something like WCF services (that could reside in windows service) and to expose all necessary information through specified contract. In this case all this application could reside on different machines, but anyway this solution more clean and robust.

Comment: plus one for the far sightedness. Mutexes may be a "quick fix" solution but never foolproof. :)

Answer (score 0):

For cross process locking you may either use Semaphore or Mutex. However, be aware of the difference between them. Mutex allows only ***one*** thread to enter the critical section code at a time.

On other hand, semaphore allows number of threads with ***maximum limit*** to enter the critical code section.

My advice it use Mutex if you want to avoid data inconstancy (multiple threads may alter the variables contents without coordinating with each others).

And to use semaphore if you want to limit the amount of threads using the same piece of code (aka request throttling). That is if your goal not overwhelm your application with huge number of requests in the same time.